# Calling a fragment method from an Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

I need to call a Fragment method inside my Adapter, but I get an error:

> ClassCastException: Main(MainActivity) cannot be cast to PlayPauseClick(Interface)

I implemented my Interface in my Fragment but I still get this error cause a friend already told me that `mContext` (my Adapter context) cannot be a `Fragment`.

So how can I solve this problem?

My Fragment method  :

```
private FunDapter<Product> adapter;
private ArrayList<Product> productList;
private ListView lvProduct;

adapter = new FunDapter<>(getActivity(), productList, R.layout.d_layout_list_d, dict);
lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);

// My method
@Override
public void imageButtonOnClick(View v, int position){
  playPause=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.playPause);
  Product m = productList.get(position);
  playPause.setImageResource(m.getPlayPauseId());
  playPause.setTag(position);
  playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
            Product m =(Product) productList.get(pos);
            if (paused) {
            m.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            paused=false;
            }else {
             m.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
             paused = true;
            }
       }

    });
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface PlayPauseClick{
 void imageButtonOnClick(View v, int position);
}
```

And  my Adapter:

```
public class FunDapter<T> extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable  {

protected List<T> mDataItems;
protected LongExtractor<T> idExtractor;
protected final Context mContext;
private final int mLayoutResource;
private final BindDictionary<T> mBindDictionary;
private FunDapterFilter<T> funDapterFilter;


public FunDapter(Context context, List<T> dataItems, int layoutResource,
                 BindDictionary<T> dictionary) {
  this(context, dataItems, layoutResource, null, dictionary);
}

public FunDapter(Context context, List<T> dataItems, int layoutResource,
                 LongExtractor<T> idExtractor, BindDictionary<T> dictionary) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mDataItems = dataItems;
    this.mOrigDataItems = dataItems;
    this.mLayoutResource = layoutResource;
    this.idExtractor = idExtractor;
    this.mBindDictionary = dictionary;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    final GenericViewHolder holder;
    if (null == v) {
        LayoutInflater vi =
                (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(mLayoutResource, null);
        holder = new GenericViewHolder();
        holder.root = v;



    holder.playPause=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.playPause); 
    holder.playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((PlayPauseClick)mContext).imageButtonOnClick(v, position);        
        }
    });


    return v;
}
```

Comment: did u implement the interface in your activity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to define your interface on the Fragment, then you need to explicitly set that onto the Adapter, not rely on the Context to handle that for you because `Activity` is `mContext`, not your Fragment.

So, here is your adapter with an interface defined. It gets activated when you click the button.

```
public class FunDapter<T> extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable  {

    public interface PlayPauseClick {
     void imageButtonOnClick(View v, int position);
    }

    private PlayPauseClick callback;

    ...

    public void setPlayPauseClickListener(PlayPauseClick listener) {
        this.callback = listener;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        holder.playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (callback != null) {
                    callback.imageButtonOnClick(v, position);
                }
```

And in the Fragment, you can implement that interface (aka your callback)

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment 
    implements YourAdapter.PlayPauseClick // see here

    // private ... adapter;
    private List<Product> data = new ArrayList<Product>();

    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(...) {
        // Set your adapter
        // Pass the listener here
        this.adapter = new FunDapter<Product>(...); 
        this.adapter.setPlayPauseClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void imageButtonOnClick(View v, int position) {
        // TODO: Implement this
    }
```

And you should remove the interface implementation on the Activity class.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing happens because `mContext` is an Activity and not your `PlayPauseClick`. I suggest the following:

1) When you create the Fragment give it a tag and save it in the activity:

```
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    final FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    View containerView = getContainerView();
    ft.add(containerView.getId(), fragment, tag);
```

2) Inside the adapter do the following:

```
holder.playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentManager fm = ((MyActivity)mContext).getFragmentManager();
        final MyFragment dismissedFragment = (MyFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag(((MyActivity)mContext).getMyFragmentTag());
        dismissedFragment.imageButtonOnClick(v, position);        
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you call `getFragmentManager` from an Adapter?

Comment: @cricket_007 you are right, getFragmentManager() needs the activity. I fixed the code to reflect that.

Comment: Casting to `MyActivity` is coupling the adapter to the Activity, though. Probably not the best design